# Navigation drawer with activities instead of fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

What i have is left navigation menu that i have made using navigation drawer and it works just fine with fragments , and i have five buttons each one open a fragment but now i want each case to open an activity instead of fragment , and i have tried to do it using intent but it didn't work !!
here is my code :

```
private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //fragment = new HomeFragment();
//          Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
//          startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 1:
            //fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            //fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            //fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            //fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            //fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

So what shall i change in this code so it can open an activity instead of fragment??? can anyone help me?

Comment: *but it didn't work*- and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: when i try to run it on emulator .. a black screen appeared and on the logcat it says " couldn't build fragment " even i didn't try to build one

Comment: i mean the else statement worked

Comment: Please provide the full logcat error

Comment: Please post the logcat.You seem to be on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your function to load a class Fragment in some case and in other cases a class Activity

```
case 0:
activity = new MyActivity();
fragment = null;
break;
case 1:
fragment = new MyFragment();
activity = null;
break;  

if (fragment != null) {
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, (android.app.Fragment) fragment).commit();
  setTitle(menutitles[position]);
  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}else {
  if(activity != null) {
     Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity.getClass());
     i1.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, position);
     startActivity(i1);  
     setTitle(menutitles[position]);
     mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
  }
}
```

Comment: what shall i configure activity to be?

Comment: i dont understand. can you explain your comment?

Comment: in the logcat i keep see a black screen with this :   Skipped 231 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: I initialize activity variable like this: "Activity activity = null;"

Comment: Remember that MyActivity class needs to extends Activity

Comment: yes it is but although i have change the code . it didn't work .. shall i update my code?

Comment: what is the problem now?

Comment: i keep seeing a blank screen

Comment: try to debug to see if you enter in oncreate funtion of the new Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the Error from Logcat:

What i would check first is:

- Are the Activities declared in the Manifest.xml as Activies?
- Secondly check if you calling Activities with an Intent, and not Fragments

This is how you start Activities correctly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, class1); // class1 The class to open
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: could you please post the Logcat error when trying to start over Intent :)